# Breadcrumb trail text wrapping issue in panel, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, web-applications

Form my menu, I dynamically create a breadcrumb trail in a Panel using LinkButtons and Labels. I cannot get it to wrap correctly though no matter what I do.

1. Panel: Wrap=True, Width=400px, ScrollBars=None
2. LinkButton: style="white-space: nowrap"
3. Label: text=">", so there is no whitespace
4. margin-left: 5px for  and  inside the Panel

With LinkButton style white-space set to "nowrap", the panel doesn't automatically wrap the text.

```
Home > Chevy > Trucks > Silverado > Engineering Department > Fuel System
```

With LinkButton style white-space set to "normal" it wraps but not what i need.

```
Home > Chevy > Trucks > Silverado >
 Engineering 
Department >
Fuel
System
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
Home > Chevy > Trucks > Silverado >
Engineering Department > Fuel System
```

This is my codebehind to create the link when a menu item has been selected.

```
 Private Sub CreateLink(name As String, id As Integer)
    Dim link As LinkButton
    Dim lbl As Label

    link = New LinkButton
    link.Text = name
    link.SkinID = id
    link.Style.Add("white-space", "nowrap")
    AddHandler link.Click, AddressOf Links_Click
    BreadCrumbPanel.Controls.Add(link)

    lbl = New Label
    lbl.Text = ">"
    BreadCrumbPanel.Controls.Add(lbl)
 End Sub
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML markup look like?

Comment: @dspencer I solved the issue for the most part, I guess I posted this quesion to soon. At any rate thanks for taking a look at it, my answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up setting the panel width to 100% instead of fixed with and now the result looks like below. Either result is exceptable for my needs.

Result A

```
Home > Chevy > Trucks > Silverado > 
Engineering Department > Fuel System
```

Result B

```
Home > Chevy > Cars > Volt > Sales 
Department > Information
```